# Windows(x64)環境におけるセキュアプログラミング

Tags: windows, security

Windows環境において、解析されづらいライブラリやアプリケーションを開発しようとした際に、どのような技術があるのでしょうか？

ネットで調べたところ、Intel SGX(Software Guard eXtensions)が該当するのかなと思ったのですが、2021年からリリースしている第11世代Core iプロセッサシリーズから廃止になっていると知り、代替案が何かないか探しています。

インテル® ソフトウェア・ガード・エクステンションズ (インテル® SGX)
https://www.intel.co.jp/content/www/jp/ja/architecture-and-technology/software-guard-extensions.html

Intel SGXが廃止されたことで、PCのUHD BD再生ができなくなるなどの弊害も出ているようなので、Intel SGX程の代替案はないと思うのですが、Windows上でのアプリケーションや難読化手法について、Intel SGX以外の方法にどのようなものがあるか教えていただけないでしょうか？

https://av.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/topic/1383999.html

Comment: セキュアって目的によって実装手段が全然違います。難読化って結局セキュアではないのでどういうことから何をどう守る・・・みたいに話をある程度限定しないと発散しちゃうんぢゃないかな・・・

Answer (score 1):

メモリ上に展開されたプログラムがSGXで保護されたとして、読み込む前のディスク上のファイルに対しては保護できないので、結局のところ実行ファイルを難読化するしかない気がしています。
で、自力で難読化するとウイルス扱いされるだけなので既製ツールを使うわけですが、それらのツールはディスク上の実行ファイルだけでなく、メモリ上でも保護する努力がされているので、そこで完結してしまう、みたいな。

ツールとしては[Packer](https://eset-info.canon-its.jp/malware_info/term/detail/00084.html)とか呼ばれています。リンク先はウイルス観点でしか説明されていませんが、例えばAdobeのプログラムの一部は難読化されてたりします。なお、こっちの[Packer](https://www.packer.io/)とは別物です。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。
Packerについて調べてみます。